# How to restart an Observable with a filter without touching the filter?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a timer based observable that does periodic updates to a rest resource. The user has the ability to disable the updates. The simple example code is

```js
export class MyThingComponent {
  data$: Observable<string>;
  userControlledEnabledFlag: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    this.setObservable();
  }

  setObservable() {
    this.data$ = timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(filter((x) => this.userControlledEnabledFlag))
      .pipe(mergeMap((x) => of('Observable of interest ' + x)));
  }

  restartAction() {
    this.setObservable();
  }
}
```

The ui is also simple:

```html
<p>
  {{ data$ | async }}
</p>

<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="userControlledEnabledFlag" /> Keep updating

<button (click)="restartAction()">Restart</button>
```

[image]

Due to the the timer observable I get the first result instantly and then an update once a second as long as the user has the checkbox checked.
When I hit "Restart" while the checkbox is checked, the timer observable is reset, the filter does not kick in and the observable proceeds to `mergeMap`.

But when the checkbox is not checked and I hit restart, then the filter does not propagate the observable chain to `mergeMap` and the `of('Observable of interest ' + x))` is never emitted.

[image]

I know this is working as designed, but not as I intended

How can I design the observable chain to allow me to restart, get one single `of('Observable of interest ' + x))` and then honour the `userControlledEnabledFlag` ?

More context: I don't want to set `userControlledEnabledFlag` to true when hitting "Restart" because then the chain would be constantly executed changing the users intent. When the user disabled updates, the restart should at provide data once.

I could create some very ugly code where the filter will pass once, e.g. setting `userControlledEnabledFlag` to true and then back to false with another helper bool, but I am sure there is a better way.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-angular-cmvkfh?file=src/app/my-thing/my-thing.component.ts)

I am a novice dealing with observables, so I probably went down the wrong path. Therefore any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when the flag is `true` you want to continually poll for the data.  When the flag is `false` you only want it one time.  When the flag changes values, you want to immediately get the data.

If that's the case, you can do something like this:

```
export class MyThingComponent {
  
  private userControlledEnabledFlag$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  data$: Observable<string> = this.userControlledEnabledFlag$.pipe(
    switchMap(pollingEnabled => !pollingEnabled
      ? this.getData()
      : timer(0, 1000).pipe(
          exhaustMap(() => this.getData())
        )
    )
  );

  setFlag(value: boolean) {
    this.userControlledEnabledFlag$.next(value);
  }

  private getData(): Observable<string> {
    return of('Observable of interest');
  }

}
```

Here we use a `BehaviorSubject` as a way to manually push the value of the flag.  We declare the `data$` to start begin with the flag value and pipe it to a new observable that either executes one time, or polls, based on the value of the flag.

And the template would look something like this:

```html
<p>
  {{ data$ | async }}
</p>

<input #input type="checkbox" (change)="setFlag(input.checked)" />

<button (click)="setFlag(input.checked)">Restart</button>
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75757995?devtoolsHeight=50&file=src%2Fmy-thing%2Fmy-thing.component.html,src%2Fmy-thing%2Fmy-thing.component.ts) example.

Comment: That's it! I don't understand it yet but the stack blitz shows the behaviour I was trying to achieve. Thanks. Will extend my knowledge about RxJS now :)

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do it with iif rxj operator:

```js
export class MyThingComponent {
  data$: Observable<string>;
  userControlledEnabledFlag: boolean = true;

  default$ = (val) => of('Observable of interest ' + val);

  constructor() {
    this.setObservable();
  }

  setObservable() {
    let value;
    this.data$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      mergeMap((x) =>
        iif(
          () => this.userControlledEnabledFlag,
          this.default$(x).pipe(tap((x) => (value = x))),
          of(value)
        )
      )
    );
  }

  restartAction() {
    this.setObservable();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimal-angular-fgpgqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-thing%2Fmy-thing.component.ts

Comment: If I uncheck the box and hit restart, I don't get any observable result in your stack blitz. Can you confirm this?